# how to allow latin and cyrillic alphabet in jquery musk

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to allow latin and cyrillic alphabet im my input form

```html
<input name="FirstName" id="FirstName" asp-for="FirstName" type="text" placeholder="@ViewBag.DataModels.FirstNamePlaceholder" required>
```

```js
//script
$("#FirstName").mask("aaa?aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", {
  "placeholder": ""
});
```

this allow only latin

Comment: Can you specify exactly which plugin you're using? I don't believe the jQuery core has a `.mask()` (Ideally with a link and version number, since there can be quite a lot of variation in some plugins)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.